# Ilford Rapid Fixer color

Tags: film, black-and-white, fixer

I'm very unfamiliar about color chemistry at all. I use different films and developers for my needs in B&W. There is only one constant is my workflow.
I always use:

- **Ilford Ilfostop Indicator stop bath** which is originally orange when concentrated and yellow when diluted
- **Ilford Rapid Fixer** is transparent but I suppose some amount of stop bath mixed into fixer

Recently I decided to wash out some silver from my very old spoiled *color films* with outdeveloping them. I've just put my films to black and white fixer.

Unexpectedly fixer changed it's color to purple. So I'm but surprised about this:)
What may root cause of this? Is it stop bath indicator reaction on color film or just washed dye?

Main question **Is my fixer still usable?**
I know fixers are very resistant to pollution by other chemistry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How purple is it?

Indicator stop solution will turn purple when it's used up, i.e. when the pH gets above a certain threshold. It sounds like some of the stop bath found its way into your fixer and changed color due to the higher pH of the fixer.